# how to know if script is loaded

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to load a script like:

```js
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
};

loadjscssfile("js/view/Header.js", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
```

How can I make sure the script was fully loaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onload`

```
fileref.onload = function(){
  alert("Loaded");
};
```

before setting the `src`.

Comment: what about his `fileref` being not in global scope for final `if` condition?

Comment: I didn't get it @gurvinder372

Comment: @gurvinder372 i don't think that will be a problem, it will never be out of scope inside the function.

Comment: `var fileref=document.createElement('script')` is inside the first if condition, his second if condition uses that `fileref` variable.

Comment: @gurvinder372 javascript does not have block scope, it just has function scope, i hope you are aware of this.

Comment: Glad. :) @AlvaroJoao if it solves your problem please consider voting it up and marking it as right answer.